# How to send a notification to multiple devices using APNS

Tags: php, curl, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send a notification to about 20'000 devices using the APNS

In firebase you simply define an array with all the recipients but it seems like this isn't possible using the APNS interface. According to the documentation you push each message to an unique url:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/

That means that I have to loop trough 20k device tokens and open 20k HTTP connections to the endpoint. This seems very wrong to me.

What is the correct way to send the same message to multiple devices using apples APNS?